# Como verificar se uma classe está usando um Trait?

Tags: php, trait

Como podemos saber se uma classe usa um Trait?

Por exemplo:

```
trait Setter
{
   protected $vars = [];

   public function __set($key, $value)
   {
       $this->vars[$key] = $value;
   }
}

class User
{
   use Setter;
}

$user = new User;

if ($user contém o trait Setter) {
   // faça alguma coisa
}
```

De acordo com o código indicado, como saber que `$user` está utilizando o `trait` `Setter`?

Comment: Wallace hoje está demais com as perguntas :) +1

Comment: As vezes eu já até sei a resposta para algumas, mas pergunto só pra ter no SOPT :)

Comment: Eu sei Wallace :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe no PHP uma função que é o `class_uses`.

Vê no link [class_uses](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-uses.php)

Comment: Então, assim, temos para o `php 5.4 >` a seguinte forma de verificar se existe `isset(class_uses($user, true)['TraitUser'])`;

Comment: @WallaceMaxters passa-se alguma coisa para a minha resposta ter sido alterada após você a ter validado

Comment: Na verdade, o `classe_uses` estava sem o ``

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/73452/revisions

Comment: sem qualquer problema... a pergunta é sua e a resposta foi curta e directa pois nada mais tenho a acrescentar. Sendo que a sua preferência vai pela solução ReflectionClass eu não a recomendo em código de produção. por isso a minha resposta no meu entender é a possível dentro da pergunta efectuada... o resto é consigo. sem drama!

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra maneira de se descobrir se o trait existe numa classe é através do método `RelectionClass::getTraits`

Veja:

```
$reflection = new ReflectionClass('MyClass');

if (in_array($trait, $reflection->getTraits())) {

    // Trait existe
}
```

Ou:

```
$reflection = new ReflectionClass('MyClass');


if (isset($reflection->getTraits()[$trait])) {

    // Trait existe
}
```